# How to create and SSIS Dashboard for SSIS packages monitoring

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2012, ssis-2008

I am new to SSIS. I have created few packages in SSIS which basically insert data from SQL Server to Oracle DB. Can someone assist me in creating dashboard which shows me execution status of Packages. 
For ex: When it was last executed, When is the next execution time, What was last execution status, How many packages succeeded or failed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there are also options outside the management studio.

For example you can create a dashboard in grafana (I use it like this), I share a repository with examples to create it.

https://github.com/OsirisDBA/grafana-ssisdashboard

There is also a development that can be mounted on docker, also very interesting.

https://github.com/yorek/ssis-dashboard

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Reporting with the SQL Server Integration Services Catalog". 
If you deploy your project to SQL-SERVER catalog and then execute your packages(by job agent or Ad hoc execution) then you can use the reports from the SSMS.
**Steps to achieve this method:**

1. Open integration services catalog.
2. Open projects.
3. Right-click on your solution - reports - standard reports - all executions.

[image]

For more information, you can enter this link
[Reporting with the SQL Server Integration Services Catalog](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4812/reporting-with-the-sql-server-integration-services-catalog/)